# Stop recording once volume is below threshold with python-sounddevice

Tags: python, audio, sox, python-sounddevice

I currently have some python code that constantly records 4-second chunks of audio:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sounddevice as sd

fs = 16000

while True:
    print('Started listening')
    myrecording = sd.rec(int(4 * fs), dtype='int16', channels=1, blocking=True)
```

However, instead of having a fixed 4-second chunk, I would like `sounddevice` to record until the volume of the drops below a threshold of audio (ie, when the person with the microphone has stopped talking), and then start listening again.

Essentially, I want to mimic the behaviour of a command like `sox`'s `rec recording.wav silence 1 0.1 3% 1 3.0 3%`, which does exactly this.

Is there an easy way to do this with `sounddevice`?

Comment: The `sounddevice` module cannot help you with the signal analysis, its job is just providing the signal. But you can write your own hand-written callback function that does the analysis and use that in a `sounddevice.InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the libraries that do this are called VAD (voice audio detection). For python, a good one seems to be [py-webrtcvad](https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad).